# weird behaviour when use interactive rebasing to reoder commit

Tags: git

Let's say we have the following workflow:

```
D <- HEAD, branchB
|
C
|
B
|
o <- branchA
```

and I ran the `git rebase -i branchA`, then I reordered the commits as:

```
pick   D
pick   B
fixup  C
```

then I have sth like :

```
o  o
|  |
o  o
| /
o <- branchA
```

I'm confused, isn't that I need to get a linear line(with reordered nodes) like:

```
o  
|  
o 
|
o 
| 
o <- branchA
```

why I have a new "leaf"?

Comment: You should display the refs (branches, remotes, tags) in your 2 last graphs that could explained why commits are still visible.

Answer (score 1):

`rebase` by default modifies the current branch, the branch that `HEAD` points to. Other branches are kept intact, so if you run `git log --graph --all` you could end up with a commit graph like that.

E.g. if you have

```
A--B--C--D--E (master, HEAD -> branch)
```

you do `git rebase -i HEAD~3` and modify the commits, you get

```
A--B--C--D--E (master)
    \
     C'--D'--E' (HEAD -> branch)
```

Comment: do you mean master, branch , head all point to `E` in the beginning? if yes , I couldn't replicate it, I still get a linear line graph

Comment: Yes. You need to actually modify at least the first commit during the rebase. What tool do you use to look at the commit graph?

Comment: "modify at least the first commit", do you mean commit `C`? I used sourcetree

Comment: Edit or reorder, change it in some way for it to have a different hash. Sourcetree shows all branches in the graph. Branches *can* diverge, and there will be multiple leaves in the commit graph until you merge them. You could add a screenshot of the graph in your original question.